# In Perl, what is the difference between s/^\s+// and s/\s+$//?

Tags: regex, perl

I know that the following three lines of codes aim to extract the string into $value and store it in $header. But I do not know what are the differences between `$value =~ s/^\s+//;` and `$value =~ s/\s+$//;`.

```
$value =~ s/^\s+//;
$value =~ s/\s+$//;
$header[$i]= $value;
```

Comment: "I know that the following three lines of codes aim to extract the string into $value and store it in $header" ... just for the record, they don't. They aim to strip whitespace from the ends of the scalar $value and place it in the $i-th element of the array @header.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [`perldoc perlfaq4`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-strip-blank-space-from-the-beginning%2fend-of-a-string%3f):

> **How do I strip blank space from the beginning/end of a string?**
>
> A substitution can do this for you. For a single line, you want to
>   replace all the leading or trailing whitespace with nothing. You can
>   do that with a pair of substitutions:
>
> ```
> s/^\s+//;
> s/\s+$//;
> ```
>
> You can also write that as a single substitution, although it turns
>   out the combined statement is slower than the separate ones. That
>   might not matter to you, though:
>
> ```
> s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
> ```
>
> In this regular expression, the alternation matches either at the
>   beginning or the end of the string since the anchors have a lower
>   precedence than the alternation. With the `/g` flag, the substitution
>   makes all possible matches, so it gets both. Remember, the trailing
>   newline matches the `\s+`, and the `$` anchor can match to the
>   absolute end of the string, so the newline disappears too.

---

And from [`perldoc perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Simple-word-matching):

> To specify where it should match, we would use the anchor
>   metacharacters `^` and `$` . The anchor `^` means match at the
>   beginning of the string and the anchor `$` means match at the end of
>   the string, or before a newline at the end of the string. Some
>   examples:
>
> ```
> "housekeeper" =~ /keeper/;         # matches
> "housekeeper" =~ /^keeper/;        # doesn't match
> "housekeeper" =~ /keeper$/;        # matches
> "housekeeper\n" =~ /keeper$/;      # matches
> "housekeeper" =~ /^housekeeper$/;  # matches
> ```

Answer (score 1):

^ means starts with, $ means ends with this string.

Comment: You described `\z`, not `$`. `$` matches the end of the string or before a newline at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The first one will only replace whitespace at the beginning of the line.